# Why does the iphone not honor max-width: 100%?

Tags: html, css, iphone

In my web browser if squeezed and my Android phone 100% works perfectly. Not so on iphones checked.

For images I commonly use max-width: 100%; and when the situation suits width: 100%; or img-responsive. The image is larger than 600px wide; thus I set width to 600px to control that on larger devices.

```
<section class='section20'>
<figure class="image">
<img src="images/user-content/1/20221003160546.jpg">
</figure>
</section>
```

The CSS:

```
.section20 .image,
.section20 img {
width: 600px !important;
max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Adding !important or not makes no difference. The formatting editor is CKEditor 5. It is rather strick in how the classes are handled in the code. If you add your custom class in code view it will strip it out of figure when return to formatting editor view.

```
<figure class="image">
<figure class="image my-custom-class">
```

custom-class would get stripped out.

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet? And have you got a meta element in the head? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your selectors.

Using `.section20 .image` is instructing the `img` wrapper to stay at `600px` and won't resize with `max-width: 100%;`.

Use `.image img` instead.

```css
.image img {
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class='section20'>
  <figure class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
  </figure>
</section>
```

Comment: Thx for pointing out my mistake. I checked with my client and it solved the problem. Can't believe I missed that. Still, the question remains why the original CSS worked on my Android phone but not iPhone. I can live without that knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Do not hardcode widths and heights. Go for rem or vw/vh(recommended).

```
.section20 .image,
.section20 img {
width: 35rem ; // or type the equivalent rem value
max-width: 100vh ; 
}
```

means the height of this element is equal to 100% of the viewport height.